# Debug htaccess file with www and https redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am attempting to get a website working with `www -> non-www` redirect and `http -> https` redirect. The http version is redirecting to https but the www version is not redirecting to non-www version, which is currently loading nothing but `pageok`.

This isn't really my area, unfortunately.

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^ourdomain\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # Redirect www to non-www first 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

  # Then redirect http to https (if necessary)
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: What URLs do you have in WP as home and site URL?

Comment: Your canonical redirects should come at the top of your .htaccess file.